# What tense is this sentence in from Selena Gomez's emotional monologue?

Tags: tense

The music video for The Heart Wants What It Wants opens with Gomez's monologue: ''...But I didn't realize that feeling so confident and feeling so great about myself ...and then it just be completely shattered by one thing.''

My big question mark is on the use of ''be'' as in ''...and then it just **be** completely shattered by one thing.'' What kind of tense is that sentence in?
Or could it be abbreviated from ''...and then [to have] it just be completely shattered...''
Because the music video was of such high production value and the monologue was recorded with really heavy emotion, I would like to think of this special use of "be" as an intentional choice rather than a grammatical error. If so, what kind of effect does it help to achieve?

Comment: No, as the only user who answered that question simply shared their opinion that that question was of limited value....

Comment: If your original question did not get a satisfactory answer you need to improve it by editing. If you ha enough reputation you could put a bounty on it. Just posting essentially the same question is not going to help much.